# Problemas com colunas no Python XLRD

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Sou um iniciante em Python e estou tentando fazer um script para somar todos os valores de uma coluna do excel e escrever o valor da soma na planilha. Estou usando os pacotes Python xlrd e xlwt. O código funciona bem pra primeira coluna, mas a partir da segunda não funciona mais, ele informa sempre valor 0. Espero que alguém mais experiente possa me ajudar.

Obrigado!

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

workbook_page = xlrd.open_workbook('page_level.xlsx')
worksheet_page = workbook_page.sheet_by_name('Daily External Referrers')
num_rows = worksheet_page.nrows - 1
curr_row = 0
num_cols = worksheet_page.ncols - 1
curr_col = 1
soma = 0

while curr_col < num_cols:
    curr_col = curr_col + 1
    while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row = curr_row + 1
        row = (worksheet_page.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col))
        if isinstance (row, float):
            soma = soma + row
        else:
            pass
    worksheet_page.write(num_rows+1, curr_col, soma)
worksheet_page.save('page_level.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu problema parece estar na forma de progressão dos loops:

```
while curr_col < num_cols:
    curr_col = curr_col + 1
    while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row = curr_row + 1
```

Na primeira iteração do loop externo, `curr_col` passa a valer `1`, e então `curr_row` vai de `0` a `num_row` através do loop interno. Na segunda iteração, `curr_row` já é `num_rows`, de modo que ele nem sequer entra no loop interno!

Pra solucionar você precisa resetar `curr_row` para `0` antes de começar o loop interno:

```
while curr_col < num_cols:
    curr_col = curr_col + 1
    curr_row = 0
    while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row = curr_row + 1
```

P.S. Você tem certeza que o que você quer é incrementar o valor da variável primeiro e usá-la depois? Veja bem que o `cell_value` é baseado em zero, não em um... Por isso, creio que o correto seria:

```
while curr_col < num_cols:
    curr_row = 0
    while curr_row < num_rows:
        # Seu código...
        curr_row = curr_row + 1 # No __final__ do loop
    # Mais código...
    curr_col = curr_col + 1 # No __final__ do loop
```

Ou, de forma mais "pitônica":

```
for curr_col in range(num_cols):
    for curr_row in range(num_rows):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado mgibsonbr!

Eu resolvi da seguinte forma:

```
while curr_col < num_cols:
    soma = 0
    curr_col = curr_col +1
    curr_row = 0
    while curr_row < num_rows:
        curr_row = curr_row + 1
        row = (worksheet_page.cell_value(curr_row, curr_col))
        if isinstance (row, float):
            soma = soma + row
            sheet.write(0, curr_col-2, worksheet_page.cell_value(0, curr_col))
            sheet.write(1, curr_col-2, soma)
            wb.save('kpis.xlsx')

        else:
            pass
```